# constant Cross product

Tags: vectors

If vectors $\vec A,\vec B$ pass through points $P,Q$ and dot product

$$ \dfrac{\vec A\cdot \vec B}{|A||B|}=0, $$

then the locus of intersection points of $A,B$ is a sphere with diameter $PQ$

and if cross product

$$  \dfrac{|\vec A \times \vec B|}{|A||B|}=1, $$

then is the locus of intersection points of $A,B$ also a sphere with diameter $PQ?$

If not, what is the locus?

Comment: Hint: How does the magnitude of the cross-product of the vectors $A,B$ relate to the magnitudes of the vectors $A,B$ and the angle between them?

Comment: What do you mean with "vectors pass through points"? And what do you consider intersection points of vectors?

Comment: I implied positioned vectors of given diection in the plane to start with.. Should I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very well known that $$\dfrac{|\vec A \times \vec B|}{|A||B|}=|\sin\theta|$$where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec {A}$ and $\vec{B}$. Also $|\sin\theta|=1$ is exactly equivalent to $\cos\theta=0$ i.e. they have the same roots. So what you argued is correct znd the locus is still the same sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [triple product expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Triple_product_expansion) identity $\,(a \times b) \cdot (c \times d) = (a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) - (a \cdot d)(b \cdot c)\,$:

$$
|A \times B|^2 = (A \times B) \cdot (A \times B) = |A|^2\,|B|^2 - (A \cdot B)^2
$$

It follows that $A \cdot B = 0 \iff |A \times B| = |A|\,|B|\,$.